# Bad Request: Invalid filter clause

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using POSTMAN to call Microsoft Graph APIs. I am trying to subscribe to presence for multiple users. It is mentioned in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-beta) in order to subscribe to changes to multiple user presences use this url :`/communications/presences?$filter=id in ({id},{id}...)`

Request Url

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions
```

So this is request body(raw)

```
{ 
  "changeType": "updated", 
  "notificationUrl": "https://d3a8ebc3581d.ngrok.io/presence-notify/", 
  "resource": "/communications/presences?$filter=id in (abcd-efgh-4856-a935-c9a2f685xyz,abcd-efgh-47f8-9d79-eacb0fd6xyz)",
  "expirationDateTime": "2020-09-22T07:37:13Z", 
  "clientState": "secretClientState" 
}
```

I am calling this API on behalf of user i.e i am using `UserAccessToken`. This is Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-09-21T16:24:50",
            "request-id": "2cf476f0-2270-417f-a987-5c5bbc92a351",
            "client-request-id": "2cf476f0-2270-417f-a987-5c5bbc92a351"
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: I have changed first few and last few characters of both the user ids. So it's not an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing this isn't documented very clearly, but if you check the [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta#filter-parameter) documentation. You'll see that values actually need to have `'` around them.

So if you change your request to the following it should work:

```
{ 
  "changeType": "updated", 
  "notificationUrl": "https://d3a8ebc3581d.ngrok.io/presence-notify/", 
  "resource": "/communications/presences?$filter=id in ('abcd-efgh-4856-a935-c9a2f685xyz','abcd-efgh-47f8-9d79-eacb0fd6xyz')",
  "expirationDateTime": "2020-09-22T07:37:13Z", 
  "clientState": "secretClientState" 
}
```